# How do I ensure that this query sticks to indexes?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a database with two tables. The one contains accounts, and the other contains over 2 million rows containing addresses and their coordinates. Obviously with such an amount of rows, any time a query runs that doesn't take full advantage of the indexes will take minutes if not hours to complete. Unfortunately that is currently the case with one of my queries:

```
SELECT
    addr.`Linje-ID` as lineid,
    addr.`Sluttbruker` as companyname,
    addr.`Gate` as street,
    addr.`Husnr` as housenr,
    addr.`Postnr` as zip,
    addr.`Poststed` as location,
    loc.`UX_KOORDINAT` as coord_x,
    loc.`UY_KOORDINAT` as coord_y,
    loc.`ADRESSE_ID` as addr_id

FROM
    addresses addr INNER JOIN
    locationdata loc ON
        loc.`POSTSTED` = addr.`Poststed` AND
        loc.`POST_NR` = addr.`Postnr` AND
        loc.`GATENAVN` = addr.`Gate` AND
        loc.`HUSNUMMER` = addr.`Husnr`

GROUP BY
    addr.`Linje-ID`
```

The locationdata table has a primary index id as well as an index defined as (POSTSTED, POST_NR, GATENAVN, HUSNUMMER). Fetching rows from the table using those columns in that order goes very quickly. The query above, however, had to be cancelled as it was taking too long (>15 minutes).

As my MySQL client (HeidiSQL) freezes while queries are performed, it's getting very tedious to force the application shut and start over for every attempt to fix this problem, so I'm asking for help here.

Just for testing, the table "addresses" only contains one row at the moment.

Can anyone identify why this query 'never' completes?

---

This is the EXPLAIN results I was asked for
http://pastebin.com/qWdQhdv5

You should copy the content and paste it into a larger container as it linebreaks.

---

EDIT: I've edited the query to reflect some of your replies. It still uses over 300 seconds where it shouldn't need 1.

Comment: Please explain why do you need the distinct keyword.

Comment: Also if possible provide the output of explain for this query (run `explain select distinct... your query`).

Comment: you have DISTINCT on a query using GROUP BY... God, I hate what MySQL's hidden columns functionality lets people get away with.

Comment: cherouvim: That would be due to my lack of SQL know-how.

Comment: both, the `DISTINCT` and the `GROUP BY` don't serve any purpose as far as I can tell. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You need to post your table definitions and some sample data so i can figure out your current design. Not 100% sure about your joins - they worry me.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name: The groupby serves to return only one value per `Linje-ID`. Without it, the JOIN could match several rows from locationdata and return several rows with the same Linje-ID. I want the query to just return one row with the first matched locationdata row with it.
f00: Please define table definitions. It's pretty much just the data you can see I'm trying to extract plus a key of definition (POSTSTED,POST_NR,GATENAVN,HUSNUMMER)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with MySQL, but if this was in SQL Server, in all likelihood, the 4-column index you have isn't being used at all since the engine may have no idea how selective it is, or has determined it's not selective enough to be faster than doing table scans. Regardless, why join on 4 columns when you can join on an Id type column instead?

Comment: Jon Seigel: Because I didn't make the tables, and I currently hate the person that did. In any case, as I mentioned, one of the tables contain over 2 million rows. Using the indexes takes approximately a hundred-thousandth of the time it takes to search the table without them. Does the `ON` condition not take use of indexes?

Comment: In SQL Server, not necessarily. Try putting only those 4 columns from that table in the select list and see what happens. If it's a lot faster, then I suspect the query as written here isn't using the index.

Comment: Job Seigel: I already know this query isn't using the indexes. When doing fetching only information from that table, the query takes 0.001 seconds. When running my query, it takes several minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with subqueries instead of joins

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd remove the upper from `loc.GATENAVN = UPPER(addr.Gate)` since this clause is already searching in a [case insensitive mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html).

Comment: Actually, it's dependent on the collation that determines whether searching is case sensitive vs case insensitive.  But, using UPPER/etc means an index on the addr.gate column couldn't be used for that comparison.

Comment: I removed the UPPER function, the query still takes an eternity and a half to complete